# AppleScript: How can I run with elevated privileges

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript which I use to clean up macOS filenames before migrating them to Linux (like removing "/") since this is impossible to do with *nix-tools.

The script works fine, however whenever the file has some special privileges I'm prompted for admin credentials. This is not very handy when sifting through TBs of data.

I cannot find a way to supply these credentials once and let the script do its work.

I tried:

- running from Terminal as root `sudo osascript <pathtomyscript>`
- save the script as app and add it to the "Accessibility"-apps in "Security & Privacy" system settings.

Is there any way to run this completely unattended?

Answer (score 0):

It is a big security hole if somebody can run a script to access data ignoring all access privileges. Fortunately this is not possible.

The only way to run the script without entering the credentials is executing shell commands with `do shell script` lines passing the parameters `user name`, `password` and `with administrator privileges`.

However including clear text credentials in a script is another security question…

Comment: Congratulations on your 100k - bravo!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I cannot use shell script because *nix tools cannot handle "/" in filenames. Why can't I run an AppleScript, enter the necessary credentials once and the script will perform all actions with the initially supplied credentials? I don't see the difference to lets say an installer...